# Error uploading file in Smack

Tags: java, smack

I have created a chat application using the Jabber Smack API. I'm successfully receiving files (from another app named "Gajim" ) but my upload fails in a few seconds only. After the "Negotiating" transfer status, I get an "error" status.

I corrected this error by supplying a "fully qualified" jabber ID but now the transfer gets indefinitely stuck at "negotiating stream" after I accept the transfer from another (Gajim) client.

I have the following code for my swingWorker class :

```
    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer;

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {

        transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("vedant1811@jabber.org/Gajim");
        File uploadFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            transfer.sendFile(uploadFile, "test");
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            System.out.println("sendFile Error");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!transfer.isDone()) {
            if (transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
                transferLabel.setText("ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());
            } else {
                transferLabel.setText("Uploading File: " + uploadFile.getName()
                        + "   STATUS: " + transfer.getStatus());
                fileProgressBar.setValue((int) (100 * transfer.getProgress()));
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("thread.sleep error");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in the jabber server.
Using the openfire server solved all my problems

Comment: What do you think, will this code work using moongoose im server?